# I cannot include space in cells(2,1) = (value) Any workarounds?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate a sheet with a bunch of defined values that I will write in a script. I would like the script to enter a specific value in row two and from column A to AA.

Instead of using record macros (ie. "ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1=State"), I am using cells (2,1)=state and cells (2,2)=city and so on and so forth.

However, I run into an error within VBA when my values have a space/spaces between them (ie. Zip Code): "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"

I absolutely need spaces in the values. Is there any workaround here?

EDIT

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 27)) = 1
Cells(2, 1) = lead_scramble_id ds 
Cells(2, 2) = lead_city 
Cells(2, 3) = College Scramble ID 'this errors 
Cells(2, 4) = lead_state_name
```

Comment: have you tried `cells(2,3) = "Zip Code"`? Note the quotes.

Comment: Yes! But the script would only execute the lines of code with the quotes and blank out the rest. Please advise.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant sections of code?

Comment: `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 27)) = 1`
`Cells(2, 1) = lead_scramble_id ds`
`Cells(2, 2) = lead_city`
`Cells(2, 3) = College Scramble ID` this errors
`Cells(2, 4) = lead_state_name`

Comment: Don't include important content in comments. Please [edit] your question and add it there where it can be seen instead of lost in the clutter. You can also properly format it there.

Answer (score 1):

You posted this in a comment:

```
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 27)) = 1 
Cells(2, 1) = lead_scramble_id ds 
Cells(2, 2) = lead_city 
Cells(2, 3) = College Scramble ID 'this errors 
Cells(2, 4) = lead_state_name
```

`College Scramble ID` are three separate words, not one. If this is meant to refer to a variable, it may actually be called `College_Scramble_ID`. Your other variables have underscores, so I assume this one has, too.

If you are struggling to understand the difference between variables and values, consider this:

```
dim My_city as String ' this declares a variable that can hold a text value
My_city = "Amsterdam" ' this assigns the text value "Amsterdam" to the variable
Cells(2, 2) = My_city ' this writes the value of the variable into cell B2
Cells(2, 3) = "New York" ' this writes the text value "New York" into cell C2
```

`My_city` is a variable. Its value is blank after the first line of code. After the second line of code its value is "Amsterdam".  After the third line of code, the cell contains the text "Amsterdam".

A variable name can only be one word, but a variable value can contain spaces and many words, if it is a string data type.

```
Dim myVar as String
myVar = "This is an important message for all users."
msgbox myVar
```

Here, the variable `myVar` contains a complete sentence. The value of the variable is "This is an important message for all users." The last command will pop up a message on the screen and the value of the variable will be displayed in the message box.

In your code, what is `lead_city`? Is it a variable? Can you post how you declare it? Can you post the code that assigns a value to the variable?

So, what is `College Scramble ID`? It cannot be a variable, because variable names cannot be multiple words with blanks between them. Where in your code does `College Scramble ID` come up first?

Comment: Yes I think this is the issue here - as a note, @Zeta, you should always put Option Explicit at the top of your code, so that VBA warns you when you refer to a variable that you haven't defined before.

Comment: Hey teylyn, it is not a typo but is there anyway to have space in my values (ie workarounds)? If not, I'll just adapt my entire script..
@Grade'Eh'Bacon thanks, I'll apply that!

Comment: @Zeta No - there is no way to name a "two word" variable; you will need to be consistent and always format as a single word.

Comment: @Zeta, you talk about "values" but these are not values, they are variables. There is a rogue `ds` in the statement for `cells(2,1)` , too. Do you understand the difference between a value and a variable? Do you want to use the ***text*** "College Scramble ID" ?? It is really not clear what you are trying to do. Post more code. How do the variables get their values?

Comment: I define values as a constant and cannot be changed. In my code, I am effectively naming cells 1 to 27 in row two with specific values. I think this is evident in my code and purpose of the script. I am still new to VBA, which is why I am posting in this community. If that is not the definition of values/variables, please teach me the difference.

Yes, I would like to include multiple words/text in my cell values/variables.

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer.